# How to enforce full evaluation inside async?

Tags: haskell, asynchronous, lazy-evaluation, ghc

I am playing with async library and trying to figure out its API in practice. I've noticed a strange behavior I didn't expect. It looks like a bug, but maybe it's a feature and I just need to know a workaround.

```
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Concurrent.Async

> withAsync (putStrLn "HELLO") (\_ -> putStrLn "WORLD")
WORLHEDL
```

The snippet above is working just fine - both line lines executed, but more complex async body is evaluated partially.

```
> withAsync (putStrLn "XXXXXXXXXX" >> putStrLn "HELLO") (\_ -> putStrLn "WORLD")
WOXRXLXDX
```

See, the second putStrLn is not executed.
I guess I need to wrap the whole async body in some sort of bnf, but it looks weird anyway. Why withAsync doesn't do that for me?

---

forkIO works just right, but I don't want to bother with unlifting.
async has pair library unlift-async which propagates monad automatically.

```
forkIO (Prelude.putStrLn "XXXXXXXXXX" >> Prelude.putStrLn "HELLO")
ThreadXIXdX X1X1X3X
XXX
HELLO
```

---

I found lifted-base with fork function. It works as forkIO and pass parent monad to child thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`withAsync` interrupts the forked thread (1st argument) when the main thread (2nd argument) terminates. This is explicit in the [documentation of `withAsync`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/async-2.2.2/docs/Control-Concurrent-Async.html#v:withAsync):

> **When the function returns or throws an exception, `uninterruptibleCancel` is called on the `Async`.**
>
> (...) This is a useful variant of `async` that ensures an `Async` is never left running unintentionally.

**If you want to just fork a thread, use `async`.**

```hs
async (putStrLn "XXXXXXXX" >> putStrLn "WORLD") >> putStrLn "HELLO"
```